# how to pass system symbol to char*

Tags: c

i have the follwing code:

```
char* id = someFunction();
if (id == "0x01") {
    id = ....
}
```

so, what i basically need - is to check, if in the `id` variable i have the string value "0x01", and if yes, then pass there the `{0x01, 0x00}` system symbols instead of it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this a C++ question or a C question? The answers are very different.

Comment: the project was initially written under c, but after there were some modifications done under c++. though i removed the c++ tag anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

this function is available in `string.h`

```
Example:

printf( "Enter your name: " );
scanf( "%s", name );
if( strcmp( name, "Mary" ) == 0 )
  printf( "Hello, Dr. Mary!\n" );
```

Answer (score 4):

If this is C++, use a `std::string`. Otherwise, use `strcmp` to compare.

**C/C++ is not a language**. Stop using both tags unless they're really necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Start using `std::string` and you will have no problem with such things:

```
std::string id = someFunction();
if (id == "0x01") {
    id = "0x00";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strcmp`. Or its more secure counterpart `strncmp`.

Something like this:

```
if (!strncmp(id, "0x01", 10)) {
    // they're equal!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** compare strings with `==`.

Depending on your OS etc, you could use `std::string` or the C `strcmp()` funcs

DavidRF comments that you **can** compare strings with `==`, and he is 100% correct.

```
printf("%s\n", ((char *)"hello" == (char *)"hello") ? "yes" : "no")
```

Using `==` is comparing the pointers. If the pointers are equal, then you know that the strings are equal. You can use that to short circuit the whole string compare (although it borders on trying to be smarter than the compiler - a good `strcmp` will already have this check in it).  If the pointers are not equal, then you don't know anything about the strings they point to (they could still be equal).

The specific `printf` sample above is really bad: I haven't read the C standard recently, but if memory serves correctly, putting literals into a table is compiler specific behavior. Worse still, I bet it depends on compiler options (optimization levels etc). The line may work in debug mode, then give a different result in release mode - which is never good.

Comment: Yes you can and this compile without warning: printf("%s\n", ((char *)"hello" == (char *)"hello") ? "yes" : "no"); but is not valid :)

Comment: You are correct but not helpful. I've edited my answer to address your concern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `strcmp()` function to compare strings:

```
if (strcmp(id,"0x01") ==0) {
   // match found.
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is C you want the [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) function:

```
if (!strcmp(id, "0x01")) {
    // Do the id == "0x01" code
}
else {
    // Do the id != "0x01" code
}
```

`strcmp()` returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:

1. A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.
2. A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 (id) than in str2 ("0x01")
3. And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.